# Angular 2 binding not working

Tags: javascript, angular, binding

I have a component which asks a user to a service

Parent component ts:

```
    constructor(private router:Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService){
            super();
            this.state = 0;
            userService.getById(params['id']).subscribe(this.setUser);
        }

setUser(user:UserModel){
        this.user = user;
        if (user) this.state = user.profile ? 2 : 1;
        console.log("assinging well", user, state);
    }
```

And its template:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="state">
    <div *ngSwitchCase=0>
        <user-form (formSubmitted)="save($event)"></user-form>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase=1>
        <profile-form [user]="user" (formSubmitted)="save($event)"></profile-form>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase=2>
        <curriculum-form [user]="user" (formSubmitted)="save($event)"></curriculum-form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `console.log` in setUsers prints data correctly, the user is loaded, and the state is 1.

But the template is still renderizing the case for 0, its not beign reloaded or updated. If the state is set to 1 in the constructor, the switch chooses the component I want, but the user passed by input doesn't get updated (is undefined).

@Edit:

The child component:

```
@Input() user:UserModel;

onSubmit() {
        console.log(user);
        let model = this.profileForm.value;
        this.formSubmitted.emit(model);
    }
```

The console.log prints `undefined` when the form is submitted

Comment: try `*ngSwitchCase="0"` with double quotes

Comment: I did it like that at the first time, then I changed it to `*ngSwitchCase=0` to see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, when I pass the method `setUser` as an argument, it is not binded to the instance, when it is executed, it doesn't have access to the property values. 
I changed `userService.getById(params['id']).subscribe(this.setUser);` for `userService.getById(params['id']).subscribe(this.setUser.bind(this));` and it worked